# Create sub-headers for dynamically created table headers in html

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to create a table with few of its column created dynamically, based on database values. Till here things are going good. Now only for the dynamic table headers, I want to create two sub-headers for each header being generated under the  columns for showing two different fields. How can this be achieved. Till now what I am trying is not sufficient and needs some insights. So please take a look to my code where 'Module' is the column that is being generated dynamically based on number of modules in database and under each of 'Module' column I want to put 'Attempt' and 'Result' sub-headers. Any help/insight will be very helpful.

```
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">S.No.</th>
    <th rowspan="2">E-mail ID</th> 
    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                <?php 
                     $query_select = "SELECT id from tbl;";
                     $result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());
                     $rows = array();
                      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
                          $rows[] = $row;
                    foreach($rows as $row){ 
                          $mid = $row['id'];
                    echo "<th style='width:5%' colspan='2'>Module ".$mid."</th><tr><th>Attempt</th><th>Result</th>";
                     } ?>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id FROM tbl;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
?>
    <th style='width:5%' colspan='2'>Module <?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
    <br><tr><th>Attempt</th><br><th>Result</th></tr>
<?php
}                                                               
?>
```

I have updated your code to mysqli from mysql mainly because it dated and doesn't have all the updated features. I would start learning mysqli to keep up with the competition, and to stop bugs later down the line.

$conn = you should rename this to your database variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time. But I am afraid this does not solves the issue. Now my table is weirdly unstructured. Something else can be done??

Comment: Would it be possible to see the outcome of this ^